# How to add the file in docker

Tags: docker, chatbot

I am new to docker, I installed docker as per the instructions provided in the official site.

```
# build docker images
docker build -t iky_backend:2.0.0 .
docker build -t iky_gateway:2.0.0 frontend/.
```

Now, while I am running these commands in the terminal after the installation of docker, I am getting the below error. I tried with by adding `sudo` also. But no use.

> unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/esh/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Your `docker images` should execute just fine (may require sudo if you are unable to connect to docker daemon).

`docker build` requires a `Dockerfile` to present at the same directory (you are executing at your home folder - dont do that) or you need to use `-f` to specify the path instead of .

Try this:

```
mkdir build
cd build
```

create your Dockerfile here.

```
docker build -t iky_backend:2.0.0 .
docker images
```